# How to flush shared library function from cache in C

Tags: c, operating-system, shared-libraries, shared-memory, cpu-architecture

I have created shared library which has matrix multiplication implementation logic. I am executing two different program and calculating matrix multiplication from both program by calling shared library. Only one copy of shared library is loaded into main memory and I know the physical address where the shared library function is loaded into main memory ( I know only the starting address of function, don't know the ending address of the function).

The shared library will be loaded into few cache sets (lets say from X - Y ) .  **clflush(address)** is used to flush from CPU cache . So I can use **clflush(address)** to flush out from CPU cache.

Here are my questions

1. If I use clflush(address) , it will only flush content of cache where the address mapped in CPU cache ( set X). So how to calculate the access time to access that memory address ?

Is it like

```
    // Before clflush 

    memory address P = &function(); // physical address

    start=timer();
    access memory address P; // starting address pointing to cache set X
    end=timer();

    time_needed1= end-start ;

    // Second access

    start=timer();
    access memory address P; // starting address pointing to cache set X
    end=timer();

    time_needed2= end-start ;
```

// flush out from CPUcache

```
    clflush(memory address P) ;

// After clflush 
    start=timer();
    access memory address P; // starting address pointing to cache set X
    end=timer();

    time_needed3= end-start ;
```

I am expecting time_needed3 will be **higher** than time_needed2, but I am getting **lower** value that indicates clflush is not working here.

1. **What should be the type of pointer P ?** What should I pass in place of P ?
2. As I am using integer array for matrix multiplication , so will P = P + 16 will point to next cache set ? ( cache block size is 64Bytes and size of Integer is 4Bytes ).
3. How to find the end of function ? Is it possible ? Will P=P+16 will cause fault in case it exceeds boundary of shared function ?

I am using GCC under Linux. Any help or pointer in this direction will be great help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you know the *physical* address?

Comment: printing the address of shared function.

Comment: If you mean you did something like `printf("%p\n", &function);`, then that's a virtual address.

Comment: yes, I have used the above , but in my system virtual address is 48 bit, physical address of 36 bit . So as page size is 4K (12 bit) then 36bit (VPN) and 24bit(PFN). when I print above I got 6digit address ( 24bit) . That's why it is Physical address.

Comment: Yes, the 12 lsbs are the same for virtual and physical address.  But the msbs will typically be different.

Comment: Thus as you are passing a virtual address to `clflush`, it is not clear what the behaviour of this code might be.

Comment: I tried to flush , but result shows flushing is not happening here. Also whatever address I am getting that too not a complete physical address, last 12bit is not known. so it is difficult to find the relationship of this address to cache set .

Comment: @OliCharlesworth , I cross checked that the address I am getting is virtual address, not Physical address. After clflush , I am not getting higher access time which shows clflush not working in this case.